# Pop up for registration form in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I want to use a ajax popup for registration form in my ASP.NET page. What will be the best approach to get this. 
How can i get this thing that my database got updated without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET WebForms, I'd recommend the [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) from the AJAX Control Toolkit to display the contents of an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).